# How would mirror-handed humanoids design their tools?

Tags: technology, tools, ergonomics

There is a race of humanoids who all have type 2 ulnar dimelia. In terms of outside anatomy, their hand is the same on both sides, with a set of 4 fingers on each side. How would these people design their tools, compared to tools made for asymmetric hands?

Comment: Easier to play guitar for people with short and thick fingers

Comment: Do your creatures have thumbs?

Comment: @T.Sar No they don't

Comment: from what i google ulnar dimelia, they seems like a thumb to me and seems to be able to [grasp firmly](https://cdn.medizzy.com/GxxDgDendVL2sVOxXGH96IZKVss=/600x598/img/posts/4844028e-fb64-4b20-8402-8efb646b20a2), just the tool handle likely shape to be put in their middle section or horizontally rather than vertically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ball or Tapered Cone, or T Shaped Handles**

It seems to me that they would be able to grasp objects much larger in diameter than humans can comfortably hold. A ball like shape would fill the area of their palms well. They might actually find that the greater contact surface area gives them a better grip.

[image]

As for the cone shaped handle, it would be a wide cylinder that flares towards the bottom, giving them a grip that won't slip when they swing the handle.
[image]
[image]

They might also like T shaped handles or maybe with the side "wings" curved slightly one way or the other, ex: -( or  -| or -).

[image]

Maybe like this, but with slightly longer handles. (It's called an Ulu knife, btw).

Answer (score 1):

iam not so sure about this, and i am not biologist, but base on this google image regarding ulnar dimelia.

[image]

it seems  the fingers can work as extra thumb to grasp, now regarding tool handles,in my opinion i think it would be more convenient for them to use knuckle duster kind of handle for each side of fingers, where their finger can lock better and more secure and overall the handle is likely flat.

[image]

from:https://www.shutterstock.com/search/knuckle+duster

since i dont think a more oval/round type of handle can give a more secure grip for this unless the finger can hand lock.

[image]

from:https://www.shutterstock.com/video/clip-1042264885-hand-leg-lock-pose-element-aerial-yoga

then i think a rubber/plastic type handle is a good choice too rather than smooth handle, like this.

[image]

from:https://www.sinclair-rush.co.uk/categories/hand-grips/flexible-pvc-grips/finger-nub-grips/

for the tool itself, i think they likely just adjust the length to adjust the weight and swing, if the tool require swinging, and some angle/arch/bend for easier use and add extra force

for example this axe as reverence (you can also change it for blunt tools)

[image]

from:http://www.hurstwic.org/history/articles/manufacturing/text/viking_axe.htm

or for something that lay down and swinging is not required, something like smoke pipe as reverence (dont take that to literal just the shape, there exist some tools that have such bend, but i dont know the name i am not mechanic or doctor).

[image]

from:https://depositphotos.com/114006312/stock-illustration-pipe-shape-chart.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try interlocking your thumbs and see how that changes how tools around you lie in your fingers.

From that little experiment I learned that it would be easier to hold something firmly between your finger tips so I think fine motot tools like cutlery or a toothbrush wouldn't look entirely different from ours but be held between the fingertips of the left and right part of the hand. Other fine motor tools like scissors would need a very different shape - I could imagine scissors having a much larger handle going around both halves of the hand.

For gross motor tools there is the opportunity of having two handles to hold onto with symmetrical hands, otherwise you'd need a thicker and possibly rounder handle to help with not being able to fully oppose the other half of the hand.

Have my messy doodles of my thoughts:

[image]

You'd need to see for every specific tool though if it would be possible to handle it the same way as with an opposable thumb though or whether the design would need to be adapted.